# Redis issue with unique key

Tags: php, redis, hex, redistributable

Im fairly new to redis and new to hex.

As i understand, i need an unique key,then i can add multiple fields in it.

im going to save alot of user information using hget and hset.

I was planning to use it something like

```
"user useridHere: password $password"
```

ETC if you are see.
for example

```
user 1: password pass123
```

and to get the password

```
hget("user 1: password");
```

But because i cant serach user information without the userid, because redis is depending on the key, i dont know how i should proceed.

My user is going to login with their username and password and i need to search for a match.

as i dont want to do `user stackoverflow: password`, i need to find another way, because the username is changeable.

**How should i save my accounts in redis and search in them for their username and password for match?**

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would store the username in Redis, and then if they ever change their username, simply remove that username entry and create a new one.

Comment: but for other enteries it needs to do the username too. so i have to change them too.